# Is there a way to append all dictionary values to an array? Python

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

```
valuePairs = []
for x in range(len(dictionary)):
    valuePairs.append(variables.values(x))
    print(valuePairs)
```

with the expected result of each value in the array

```
["value1", "value2", "value3" .... ect]
```

I know this may be considered bad form but I need the values in this format 
Many thanks

Comment: What's the variable `w` ?

Comment: `values` is a method that already returns all the values of a `dict`. You seem to be thinking of `get`.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be thinking of the `get` method rather than the `values` method:

```
values = []
for x in dictionary:
    values.append(dictionary.get(x))  # equivalent to values.append(dictionary[x])
```

However, `values` is, in fact, the method you are looking for: it returns an iterator over all the values, which you can simply pass to `list`.

```
values = list(dictionary.values())
```